# increment multiple arguments in lapply

Tags: r, lapply

Is there a way to increment two arguments in an lapply function? For example

```
test <- function(pos,value){
   list[pos,value]
}

data=c(1,4,32,54) #not global
lapply(X=1:length(data),test, value=data[X])#this is the idea but the code doesnt work
```

The output would be
`list(list(1,1),list(2,4),list(3,32),list(4,54))`

Another example would be

```
test <- function(pos,value,value2){
   list(pos,value,value2)
}

data=c(1,4,32,54) #not global
data2=c(2,6,3,21) #not global
lapply(X=1:length(data),test, value=data[X], value2=data2[X]) #this is the idea but the code doesn't work
```

The output would be
`list(list(1,1,2),list(2,4,2),list(3,32,6),list(4,54,21))`

This may also help. I am pretty much trying to change the for loop into an lapply.

```
test <- function(pos,value,value2){
   list(pos,value,value2)
}

data=c(1,4,32,54) #not global
data2=c(2,6,3,21) #not global
for(i:length(data)){
  result=list(result,test(i,data[i],data2[i]))
}
```

Since the variables arent global I can't have the test function as

```
test <- function(pos){
   list(pos,data[pos],data2[pos])
}
```

I know that there is an easier way of writing this code to accomplish the same thing. But I am looking for a way to specifically increment two variables, or use the incremented value in an argument. The variables used in the examples, arent global, so I can't use them in the function and it needs to use the lapply function. In the codes, the lapply lines do not work, it was just the demonstrate the concept of what I am trying to do. Thank you.

## Edit

So after learning about the mapply function. I realized that what I want is to create an lapply function that acts like an mapply

Comment: what sort of object is `data`?

Comment: @Sotos it was a list. Sorry I am used to coding in python. I think i fixed everything correctly

Comment: You can use `Map`, `Map(c, seq_along(data), data, data2)`

Comment: @RonakShah I need to use an lapply function. The problem I am actually doing is slightly different. I just simplified it for this case.

Comment: @NikitaBelooussov I think you mean vector....`list(1, 2, 3)` = list... `c(1, 2, 3)` = vector...

Comment: @Sotos yes sorry, I am still getting used to all the names and syntax sorry. If i labeled the expected output incorrectly, feel free to fix it. I am pretty sure i got it right this time.

Comment: I think you need to include a better example also including the things which you can/cannot do.

Comment: @RonakShah can you tell me which parts you find unclear, so that I can either think up of a better example, or clear it up in the question. Since right now I can't think of anything and I know it is just because I wrote it.

Comment: Why do you need ```lapply()```? Anything that can be done in ```*apply()``` can be done with a regular loop. Plus, Ronak's suggestion of ```Map(list, var1, var2, ...)``` would match your output.

Comment: @Cole I have a bigger code that I am trying to vectorize, and I got it mostly working except this part. If it is not possible to create a lapply that functions like a mapply, I do have a for loop that I can use.

Comment: Using ```lapply()``` is just a hidden loop. It's generally equivalent to ```res<- list(); for (element in elements) {res[[element]] <- f_x(element)}``` where ```elements``` is the first argument in ```lapply()``` and ```fx()``` is the function call

Comment: And ```mapply(..., simplify = F)``` is generally equivalent to, for vectors ```x``` and ```y``` each of length 2 is ```res <- list(); for (i in 1:2) {res[[i]] <- fx(x[i], y[I])}```

Answer (score 1):

Using the "<-" assignment operator:

```
num_vec <- c(1, 4, 32, 54)

num_vec2 <- c(2, 6, 3, 21)

# Using lapply: 

lapply(seq_along(num_vec), function(x){return(c(x, num_vec[x], num_vec2[x]))})
```

Using the " = " assignment operator:

```
num_vec = c(1, 4, 32, 54)

num_vec2 = c(2, 6, 3, 21)

# Using lapply: 

lapply(seq_along(num_vec), function(x){return(c(x, num_vec[x], num_vec2[x]))})
```

In the above case the assignment operator doesnt make a difference and doesnt relate to local or global assignment.

In response to the additional query about wanting to retrieve elements based on a value in either vector:

```
num_vec = c(1, 4, 32, 54)


num_vec2 = c(2, 6, 3, 21)

test <- function(num_vec, num_vec2, val) {
  if (!hasArg(val)) {
    val <- 1:max(c(num_vec, num_vec2))
  } else{
    as.numeric(c(val))
  }

  lapply(seq_along(num_vec),

         function(x) {
           return(c(x, num_vec[x], num_vec2[x]))
         })[ifelse(
           val %in% num_vec &

             !(val %in% num_vec2),

           which(num_vec %in% val),

           ifelse(
             !(val %in% num_vec2) &

               !(val %in% num_vec2),

             0,

             ifelse(
               val %in% num_vec &

                 val %in% num_vec2,

               c(which.min(
                 which(val %in% num_vec), which(val %in% num_vec2)
               ),

               which.max(
                 which(val %in% num_vec), which(val %in% num_vec2)
               )),

               which(val %in% num_vec2)
             )
           )
         )]

}

test(num_vec, num_vec2, 54)
```

Comment: no you can assign num_vec locally inside of a function and it will work too. However, with the code above we use it to iterate over so assigning it prior to the function is more readable imo then say: 
lapply(seq_along(num_vec <- c(1,4,32,54)), function(x){return(c(x, num_vec <- c(1,4,32,54)[x]))})

Comment: Also if you found my answer satisfactory please don't forget to like it, and if it solved your problem please don't forget to accept it.

Comment: @NikitaBelooussov please see my edited answer above.

Comment: Yeah. I am going to test it, since I might just be understand something incorrectly, but this part num_vec <- c(1,4,32,54)[x], makes it seem to me that if num_vec isn't global, so the function defined in the lapply can't access it. Then the num_vec[x] won't work.

Comment: yeah. I just tested. it didnt seem to work in my case. Let me think up of a way to edit the code examples in my question better, since I think most people are finding issues with understanding what I am looking for. And it is mainly due to the code in the question not demonstrating it completely properly

Comment: are you using the examples i provided in my answer ?

Comment: so i directly and if you use the = as in the second example, it doesn't work and I think it represents my issue more correctly. So how would I do it without changing it to <-. I used this website to run it. https://rdrr.io/snippets/

Comment: I also ran it with the "=" assignment operator on that website and it worked.

Comment: yep sorry, there was a typo in mine that i didnt notice

Answer (score 1):

I guess `mapply` is a better choice than `lapply` in you case.

Assuming you have a variable number of input arguments, you can rewrite `test` as

```
test <- function(pos,...){
  list(pos, ...)
}
```

For input in your example

```
data=c(1,4,32,54) #not global
data2=c(2,6,3,21) #not global
```

using `mapply` can get you there:

```
mapply(test, seq_along(data), data, data2, SIMPLIFY = F)
```

Comment: Yes I think this the equivalent of what im looking for. Can you think of a way to create a lapply. That does the same?  Or do you think that is not possible?

Comment: I don't think it would be possible to index the `data` when using `lapply`, since you cannot keep track of the iteration, according to my limited knowledge to `lapply` function @NikitaBelooussov

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the answer by @hello_friend, you can pass arguments to the function, using lapply. From the question, I understand that you want to pass more than one argument to function. The below code tries to do that. Please have a look.

```
vec1 <- c(1, 3, 5, 7)

vec2 <- c(2, 4, 6, 8)

test <- function(pos, vec_arg1, vec_arg2){
  return(c(pos, vec_arg1[pos], vec_arg2[pos]))
}
# Using lapply: 

lapply(seq_along(num_vec), test, vec1, vec2)
```

Comment: I think this is closer, but can I input just the value at that position  instead of the entire vector

Comment: Not sure, what you mean.But going by your edit, may be `mapply` is the solution.

Comment: Yeah. I didnt know about mapply. Knowing now about it, what I want is an lapply that functions like an mapply, but I am guessing it is not possible